# problem in copying a caption of a label from a dephi app?

Tags: delphi

I have a problem. I want to copy a caption of a label from a Delphi windows application .When I copy the caption label and paste in a notepad I get some weird text like " ÇÓÜÜã ÇáãæÙÝ " !!

How do i resolve this ?

The caption/text which I am copying is in Arabic. All the fonts are installed , Arabic text is working fine. But I am encountering this problem when I am copying caption of labels only from Delphi win32 aaplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should set up the notepad app. to use the ANSI Character Set (from the open file menu) if your Delphi app. was written in an older compiler (prior to D2009).

Comment: No, still the same. Thank you

Comment: I got this.I first created a new text unit and copied all the Arabic text in that unit and saved in the project . And I get all the Arabic fonts in the same text . Voila !!! But thank you , you showed me the path.